# does explicit microsoft packages needs to install for middleware in .net core 3.1 framework like .net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.1

I was using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` (2.0.2) and  `Microsoft.AspNetCore` (2.0.2) packages as a middleware in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC web project. Are the same packages required if I upgrade this project to .NET Core 3.1 or it is implicitly referred to by the .NET Core 3.1 framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are included in the framework for dotnet core 3.1/

Comment: How can we check which packages are included in .net core 3.1 compare to .net core 2.1..as I am having some packages which are explicitly refferes in net core 2.1

Comment: All here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio